# the int value changed in For loop without being calculated

Tags: c

i am new to c, and I am building a cipher text converter. I have a main function to take a Key value (int k) from the user and pass that value to this function:

```
int ciphertextCoverter (int k)
{
    printf("key=%i\n",k);
    char ciphertext[] = "";
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");

    for (int n = 0, x = strlen(plaintext); n < x; n++)
    {
         printf("key in FOR loop: %i",k);
        if isupper(plaintext[n])
        {
            printf("key in IF loop: %i",k);
            ciphertext[n] = (plaintext[n] - 'A'+ k ) % 26 + 65;

            printf("plaintext- %i %c %i %i %i %i %i\n",k, plaintext[n],plaintext[n], plaintext[n]-'A', (plaintext[n] - 'A'+ k), (plaintext[n] - 'A'+ k) % 26, (plaintext[n] - 'A'+ k) % 26+ 65);
        }
        else
        {
           ciphertext[n] = (plaintext[n] - 'a'+ k) % 26 + 97;

        }

    }
     printf("ciphertext: %s\n",ciphertext);
    return 0;

}
```

I used printf to find out that the value of int k which I passed on from the main function has changed value in the for loop, but I want to stay as a const. Please help me! what have I done wrong?

Comment: How long do you think the array ciphertext is?

Comment: it's based on user input, so it's unknown

Comment: case of the original message needs to be preserved. Lowercase letters remain lowercase, and uppercase letters remain uppercase.

Comment: @yt123 The answer to Jim Roger's question is one.  You have declared an array of size one, so it can hold a string of length 0.  As soon as you try to write to `ciphertext[1]`, you have undefined behavior.

Comment: Don't write values like `65` and `97`.  Those are much more readable if written as `'A'` and `'a'`.  Also, 26 is probably more legible written as `'z' - 'a' + 1`, but I suppose that's debatable.  Certainly clearer if you define a constant with a name like "size_of_alphabet" or similar.

Comment: thanks @William Pursell, but is the reason why k value changed in for loop?

Comment: `k` is changing because of the undefined behavior.  You're overwriting it when you overflow the buffer.

Comment: I would strongly recommend no to implement cryptography before you master the "simple" stuff, like string operations, memory management, etc. Stick to the steps of a C course first, don't venture off the path, because it will come back to bite you. Also, don't hide `char *` by using `typedef`. It will bring you nothing. That's nonsense that is taught in courses like CS50.

Comment: Note: `(plaintext[n] - 'A'+ k ) % 26 + 65;` can fail to encode as desired when `k < 0`.

Comment: `isupper` is false is not enough to say a character is lowercase, your code may still process symbols like `!`, `@` and other characters.

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring `ciphertext` as an array of size 1, so you cannot write any data to it.  Give it some size; something like:

```
string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
char ciphertext[strlen(plaintext) + 1];
```

should work.  Just remember to write the null terminator at the end: `ciphertext[x] = '\0'`

Comment: thanks for the reply! I tried with char ciphertext[strlen(plaintext) + 1] = {0}; but I got an error message:"variable-sized object may not be initialized"...any thoughts?

Comment: @yt123 ah, yes, of course.  Don't initialize it!  Just write the null terminator at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared character array of size 1. And you are storing x characters in ciphertext[]. First declare array of any size or create array dynamically.

```
char ciphertext[] = "";
```